# jquery and creating styles, how to check if the style already exists

Tags: jquery, css, styles, head

Hi people i have looked around but cant seem to find the answer i'm looking for.

i have a search page which makes ajax calls, returns json data then creates a style based on the returned data and appends it to the  section of the DOM.
The creation of the styles is working ok, but if a new search is made the style is duplicated and so my $(#element).slidetoggle() function gets duplicated and the slidetoggle opens and closes immedietly.

ypu can see the page here: http://www.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/NEW%20Search/fullsearch_jq_keys.php

(use as test data hounslow, north london and from categories: cemeteries)
if the same search is made twice the styles for the results gets duplicated, and the slide toggle behaviour is duplicated.)

my question is how do i check if the style is already in existence.

the script that creates the style is as follows:

```
function makeCSS(id){
        var myUrl = 'getBoroughInfo.php';
        $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'myID='+id,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown){
                // Work out what the error was and display the appropriate message
            },
            success: function(myData){
                var items = myData.boroughs[0];
                //console.log('borough: '+myData.boroughs);

                $("<style type='text/css'> #link_"+items.Borough_ID+"{ color:"+items.color+"; font-weight:bold; float:left; margin-left: 10px;  cursor: pointer; padding: 1px; border: 1px solid "+items.color+";} </style>").appendTo("head");
                $("<style type='text/css'> #borough_"+items.Borough_ID+"{ color:"+items.color+"; font-weight:bold; } </style>").appendTo("head");
                $("<style type='text/css'> #searchHead_"+items.Borough_ID+"{ color:#000000; font-weight:bold; background-color:"+items.color+"; opacity: 1.0; cursor: pointer;} </style>").appendTo("head");
                //apply opacity
                //$('#borough_'+items.Borough_ID).css({});
                $('#borough_links').append('<div id="link_'+items.Borough_ID+'">'+items.Borough_Name+'</div>');
                $('#results').append('<div id="searchHead_'+items.Borough_ID+'">'+items.Borough_Name+'</div>');
                $('#results').append('<div id="borough_'+items.Borough_ID+'"></div>');
                $('#link_'+items.Borough_ID).live('click', function(){
                    $('#borough_'+items.Borough_ID).slideToggle('slow', function() {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                });
                $('#searchHead_'+items.Borough_ID).live('click', function(){
                    $('#borough_'+items.Borough_ID).slideToggle('slow', function() {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

this is the line of code that creates one of my styles:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> #link_"+items.Borough_ID+"{ color:"+items.color+"; font-weight:bold; float:left; margin-left: 10px;  cursor: pointer; padding: 1px; border: 1px solid "+items.color+";} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

so how do i check if this exists in the document already????
a simple if statement would suffice for my needs i think.

Comment: Give the style tag an ID and check whether the element with this ID exists or not. But why are you adding the style dynamically? If you have control over the HTML, why not add the style directly?

Comment: Furthermore, is `items.Borough_ID` always different for every request? If not, **that** is your problem.

Comment: hey felix, thanks for your reply, the styles were being added dynamically as there are a lot of items in the db that come under a borough of which each has a different color associated to it, and are a lot of colours so was easier to generate the styles as needed, cybernates answer with a code sample below has helped solve the issue. although your answer would work too so have upped your replies, thanks for your input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :contains selector.
e.g:

```
if($("style:contains('#link_" + items.Borough_ID + "')").length < 1)
{
    $("<style type='text/css'> #link_"+items.Borough_ID+"{ color:"+items.color+"; font-weight:bold; float:left; margin-left: 10px;  cursor: pointer; padding: 1px; border: 1px solid "+items.color+";} </style>").appendTo("head"); 
}
```

Comment: thans, so much saved me a lot of time on google, such a simple line of code, is why i love jquery so much, although the actual problem was the duplicating of the click function within the code block, not the style being duplicated, but your answer has helped me solve the issue, thanks for you help :)